# Air for mobile, SQLite encryption

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, sqlite, encryption, air

I really hope someone can help with this - I have searched everywhere for an answer but am coming up very short.

I am using Flash Builder 4.7 to package an air application for ios. Now I have a bunch of data stored within a sqllite db (which created using air) and it's encrypted as well.

I can read the encrypted db just fine running the app within the air simulator but when I publish to ios, I get the following error: "SQLError: 'Error #3138: File opened is not a database file.', details:'', operation:'open'"

In all my searching it appears as though you get this error if your password is incorrect - but it's not and it works in the simulator?

Note that the db file is packaged with the ipa and being read from the applicationDirectory - I do not need to write to it at all, simply read from.

I have tried copying the file to the applicationStorageDirectory and have the same problem plus I am testing IOS7.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What encryption (for key) do you use: as3corelib or as3crypto?
Anyway solution might be: create XML file with the same data you need in SQLIte, encrypt it with as3crypto (you can even zip that XML as an string before encrypting, so you'll get much more smaller byteArray, hence file after), save it (as binary). On the first run on iOS 7 directly create new encrypted SQLite, load binary "XML", decrypt it (unzip if needed), put data in the SQLite and delete binary "XML" permanently. This technique might work if you aren't saving in the SQLIte huge BLOB data, otherwise it might be problematic.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - the encryption I am using is the default SQLlite encryption (not sure offhand exactly what that is) however you have raised an interesting point that perhaps I should abandon the default db encryption and simply encrypt the db as a file vs an actual encrypted db. Think I will give that a try and see if that resolves my issue. Thanks!

Comment: For the Key encryption I mean how you are getting byteArray for it, you might just get it from usual String, or ex: using some library to generate encrypted data. :)
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/encrypted_database.html
Had similar problem on Android, encrypted SQLite worked on desktop and some Android devices (when just used it from the desktop's version), solution I found was to create and encrypt SQLite on the working device, this resolved the problem. :)

Comment: I create the byteArray using the built in EncryptionKeyGenerator class in Air so:

var keyGenerator:EncryptionKeyGenerator = new EncryptionKeyGenerator();

var encryptionKey:ByteArray = keyGenerator.getEncryptionKey("string here");

But will give the creation of the db on the device a try as well when I'm back at work. Thanks for all the help.